# Jolokia config for Per topic message count for Kafka for broker

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, grafana, telegraf

We are having Jolokia as our JMX agent for getting the Kafka metrics, we want to get the `Per Topic Message Count` from **Jolokia** using **Telegraf** and plot it into **Grafana**. The Kafka config for the same is as follows:

`[[inputs.jolokia2_agent.metric]]
     name       = "MessagesInPerSec"
     mbean      = "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec"
     tag_keys   = ["message"]`

The output of the graph is as follows [image]

It is not showing the output of all topics message count, also I am not sure whether the output is correct or not. 
I am not proficient in Telegraf, so I need to know whether my Kafka configuration is correct for the required metrics.

Comment: You're plotting the metric over the entire server, not dividing by each topic within (assuming you can go that granular)

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure for per topic?

Comment: I know we have it in Datadog. I'm not sure what the mbean is for it